# Is the Google's closure library broken

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library

I had downloaded the Google's closure library from the downloads list [here](https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/downloads/list) the **closure-library-20110323-r790.zip** one. I hosted this version under my IIS and ran the alltests to check if all was well but,most of the CSS and other resources were missing from the repository am i to download something else other than the zip file hosted on google code. this is just a bit from the error list

```
GET http://localhost/closure/closure/goog/net/CrossDomainRpc_test.css 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost/closure/closure/goog/net/CrossDomainRpc_test.css?123 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost/closure/closure/goog/net/iframeio_different_base_test.data? 404 (Not Found)
POST http://localhost/closure/closure/goog/net/crossdomainrpc_test_response.html 405 (Method Not Allowed)
GET http://localhost/closure/closure/goog/net/this-is-not-image-2.gif 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost/closure/closure/goog/net/this-is-not-image-1.gif 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: I believe the resources you listed are expected not to exist.

Comment: no, these files are requested async to conduct the tests, but there are not in the package. wow talk about **GoOglE**

Comment: You are correct.  I filed an issue: http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/issues/detail?id=436

Comment: Does it means all tests should run OK if i download the newer version?

Comment: I don't see that the change has landed yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> closure/closure/goog/net/CrossDomainRpc_test.css

Not present, but the name is wrong.  Need to add *.css to glob.

> closure/closure/goog/net/iframeio_different_base_test.data

Present at head.  Fixed.

> closure/closure/goog/net/crossdomainrpc_test_response.html

Present at head.  Fixed.

> closure/closure/goog/net/this-is-not-image-2.gif

Not expected.  This is a dummy call.

Sending internal CL to add *.css from that dir.  This should be visible soon.  See instructions on how to download from SVN, not zip (which are older versions)

Comment: Does it means all tests should run OK if i download the newer version?